# Error 800: Missing/empty knowledge base

Tags: java, applet, expert-system

Currently i having an Assignment of AI(Artificial Intelligence) to develop an Expert System. We are using SWI-PROLOG as our practical class learning software, and now i am trying to apply e2glite to my Assignment.

I found that e2glite is able to download from www.expertise2go.com, and this website also providing the instruction and example. According to their instruction, computer must have Java(already installed).

So now i am trying to preview the sample that i had downloaded from the website, i am able to view the interface, once i click the "START The Consultation" is giving me "ERROR 800: MUST QUIT". In debug mode, it show me "Found on line 0 (below) before character 1 null"

According to the www.expertise2go.com, the meaning of error 800 is "Missing or Empty knowledge base". But i am follow exactly as the instruction to do it. I don't know where am i doing wrong.

P/S: i can view sample from the website, but no from my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved due to the java version is too updated.
Thus i downgrade the version from Java 7 Update 25 to Java 7 Update 13.